# SQL Server 2000 dropping indexes

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

Can anybody know how to remove all the indexes from database ?

Comment: why would you want to remove all indexes?

Comment: @Mitch: I would do it on dev instances to annoy other dev'ers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using this query will create you a list of DROP statements which you can then execute:

```
SELECT 
    'DROP INDEX ' + ix.name + ' ON ' + OBJECT_NAME(ID)
FROM 
    sysindexes ix
WHERE   
    ix.Name IS NOT null
```

That should be pretty fast and take care of dropping all indices :-)

Marc

PS: ah, sorry, I just noticed this will only work in SQL Server 2005 and up. For SQL Server 2000, you'll need to use the "sysindexes" view instead... I updated my statement accordingly

Comment: in this table name is not coming it will not work 
any other script ?

Comment: sorry i got it i solve the problem. i want script for sql2000
it has some diff syntax from sql2005 so i got the answer.

Comment: will this do the same thing: "select cmd from vw_drop_idnex" ?

Comment: @djangofan: I don't know any "vw_drop_index" view, so I can't really tell if that does the same thing......

Comment: this method may work but it doesnt account for dropping any contraints that might be necessary.

Comment: @djangofan: yes, good point - obviously, you might need to drop some constraints first in order to be able to drop all indices

Answer (score 1):

Generate some sql querying the [sysindexes table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260413(SQL.80).aspx).

some thing along the lines of :

```
select 'drop index ' + i.name + '  on  ' + o.name
from sysindexes i 
inner join sysobjects o  on  i.id = o.id
where  o.name <> i.name
```

The execute the results....